# Can a grandmaster always draw?

Tags: draw, grandmaster

I was watching the Candidates recently and noticed that the commentators talking about Wesley So’s last game got annoyed that he was aiming for a draw and didn’t really have any fight in him.

A draw was agreed after only 20 odd moves, and that got me thinking - if a top grandmaster were to aim for a draw against AlphaZero for instance, would they always manage?
Can a Grandmaster force a draw?

Comment: do you want to re-ask with superGM? of course answer is still no, but i wonder if the probability is a lot higher with superGM as compared to (non-super)GM

Comment: It's fine... I think the answer covers that pretty well as well. Guess there's a reason GMs haven't drawn against an engine in ages.

Comment: About the Alphazero question - see https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32702/could-a-top-ranked-gm-draw-against-stockfish-using-drawish-opening-lines-in-clas

Comment: Maybe the slightly more pertinent question is whether a (super) GM can always draw *as white*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  It may be difficult to win against a top GM who is playing for a draw, but it's by no means impossible.

If GM's could *always* draw at will, we could stop all championship matches once either player won a game, since the outcome would be decided.  But we don't do that, because the outcome is *not* decided after one player gets one win.

Comment: 1 - is the probability that a GM can (at least) draw (when playing for a draw of course) much higher than that of an IM? 2 - what about superGM vs (non-super)GM?